# Python 3 - Regular Expression - Match string with one character less

Tags: python, regex

So I want to write a regex that matches with a word that is one character less than the word. So for example:

```
wordList = ['inherit', 'inherent']
for word in wordList:
    if re.match('^inhe....', word):
        print(word)
```

And in theory, it would print both inherit and inherent, but I can only get it to print inherent. So how can I match with a word one letter short without just erasing one of the dots (.)

Comment: It will not match `inherit`

Comment: Becuase your regex has 4 dots after `inhe`

Comment: You have a regex which matches 8-characters and you are asking why it doesn't match a 7-character word?  What is it that you really want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Edited**)

For matching only **inherent**, you could use `.{4}`:

```
re.match('^inhe.{4}', word)
```

Or `....$`:

```
re.match('^inhe....$')
```

Comment: If this is what is wanted, why not leave out the final `.?` entirely?  It is doing nothing.

Comment: I dont want to leave out the final .? entirely becuase now i can add a $ at the end and get those lengths specifically.

Answer (score 0):

A regex may not be the best tool here, if you just want to know if word Y starts with the first N-1 letters of word X, do this:

```
if Y.startswith( X[:-1] ):
    # Do whatever you were trying to do.
```

X[:-1] gets all but the last character of X (or the empty string if X is the empty string).

Y.startswith( 'blah' ) returns true if Y starts with 'blah'.